# How can I set vendor email notification recipients in WooCommerce to the vendor email and not the administrator email?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

The email settings in WooCommerce list the WordPress administrator email address and I need the email to go from the customer to the vendor, not to the administrator. Can anyone please assist? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify the WooCommerce email function to send that e-mail to the vendor e-mail. If you check `dokan_wc_email_recipient_add_seller` in dokan-lite/include/functions.php then you will see that Dokan is adding vendor e-mail with the admin e-mail to send new-order email to the vendor. Similarly, you have to do this for other email notification.